# Multiple columns matching in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, null

I have four columns (**Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4**) in a table with some millions records in SQL Server 2019.

In stored procedure, I have to pass four input parameters **@Col1, @Col2, @Col3, @Col4** and it should return success/failure whether all four values found, irrespective of column sequence. For example @Col1 can match with Col2.

Some values can be null in Col2, Col3, Col4 but Col1 will always have some data in it.

I have prepared some sample data and scenarios that I have tested.

```
CREATE TABLE SampleData(Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Col1 VARCHAR(20), Col2 VARCHAR(20), Col3 VARCHAR(20), Col4 VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO SampleData(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
SELECT 'ABC','DEF','GHI','JKL' UNION 
SELECT '123','456','789','100' UNION 
SELECT 'ABC','XYZ','','' UNION 
SELECT '9898','6565',NULL,NULL UNION 
SELECT '989844','D656555','','' UNION 
SELECT '8888','9999','7777','6666' UNION 
SELECT '1234','5678','4321',NULL UNION
SELECT '465456465',NULL,NULL,NULL
```

The Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ValidateSampleData(
 @Col1 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Col2 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Col3 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Col4 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    
    Declare @a as bit = 0, @Message VARCHAR(50) = 'Data Not Matched'
    if(@Col1 is NULL or @Col2 is NULL or @Col3 is NULL or @Col4 is NULL )
    begin
        set @a = 1
    end
 
    SELECT  @Message = 'Data Matched ' 
    FROM    SampleData SD
    where   (Col1 in (@Col1,@Col2,@Col3,@Col4) or (Col1 is null and @a = 1))
    and     (Col2 in (@Col1,@Col2,@Col3,@Col4) or (Col2 is null and @a = 1))
    and     (Col3 in (@Col1,@Col2,@Col3,@Col4) or (Col3 is null and @a = 1))
    and     (Col4 in (@Col1,@Col2,@Col3,@Col4) or (Col4 is null and @a = 1))

    and     (select sum(    (case when Col1 is null then 1 else 0 end)
                    +   (case when Col2 is null then 1 else 0 end)
                    +   (case when Col3 is null then 1 else 0 end)
                    +   (case when Col4 is null then 1 else 0 end)
                    ) from SampleData where Id = SD.Id) = 
            (select sum(    (case when @Col1 is null then 1 else 0 end)
                +   (case when @Col2 is null then 1 else 0 end)
                +   (case when @Col3 is null then 1 else 0 end)
                +   (case when @Col4 is null then 1 else 0 end))) 

    SELECT @Message
END
```

Here is some sample set of data that I tried

```
DECLARE 
@Col1 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Col2 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Col3 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Col4 VARCHAR(20) = NULL 



--Case 0  - Should not matched 
SELECT @Col1 = 'ABC', @Col2 = 'XYZ' , @Col3 = 'testtest' , @Col4 = ''  
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  

--Case 1 
SELECT @Col1 = 'ABC', @Col2 = 'DEF' , @Col3 = 'GHI' , @Col4 = 'JKL'  
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  

--Case 2
SELECT @Col1 = 'DEF', @Col2 = 'JKL' , @Col3 = 'ABC' , @Col4 = 'GHI' 
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  

--Case 3 
SELECT @Col1 = '123', @Col2 = '456' , @Col3 = '789' , @Col4 = '100'  
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  

--Case 4 
SELECT @Col1 = '1234', @Col2 = '5678' , @Col3 = '4321' , @Col4 = NULL  
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  

--Case 5 
SELECT @Col1 = '465456465', @Col2 = NULL , @Col3 = NULL , @Col4 = NULL  
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  

--Case 6 
SELECT @Col1 = '8888', @Col2 = '9999' , @Col3 = '7777' , @Col4 = '6666'  
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  

--Case 7 
SELECT @Col1 = '9898', @Col2 = '6565' , @Col3 = NULL , @Col4 = NULL
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  

--Case 8 
SELECT @Col1 = '989844', @Col2 = 'D656555' , @Col3 = '' , @Col4 = '' 
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  

--Case 9   
SELECT @Col1 = 'ABC', @Col2 = 'XYZ' , @Col3 = '' , @Col4 = ''  
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4  
 
 
--Case 10  - Should not matched
SELECT @Col1 = 'ABC', @Col2 = 'XYZ' , @Col3 = 'tet' , @Col4 = ''  
EXEC ValidateSampleData @Col1=@Col1, @Col2=@Col2, @Col3=@Col3, @Col4=@Col4
```

I have achieved desired result for some cases but its incorrect with NULL values in table. **Case 0 should not matched**

Also it doesn't look optimized and very slow on large set of data.

In simple words, I want to check if all 4 values appear in the table, with NULL matching NULL? If they do, return a match, if not, a non match?

Comment: What is your question here exactly?

Comment: @Larnu I have moved the question in the end. Data with NULL values is not giving correct result. Check the Case 0 I mentioned in sample data

Comment: Are the values in each row always different (other than NULLs)? Or could a row be `'1', '1', '2', '2'`?  Same for the parameters of the procedure, are they always different? I ask because `1,1,2,3` has four matches with `1,2,2,4`

Comment: @MatBailie All values in each row will be different

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you simply want to check if all 4 values appear in the table, with `NULL` matching `NULL`? If they do, return a match, if not, a non match?

Comment: @Larnu Correct! I should have asked in these simpler words in my questions. Thanks man

Comment: @SheikhM.Haris does `465456465,NULL,NULL,NULL` match `465456465,123,NULL,NULL` and `465456465,465456465,NULL,NULL`?

Comment: @SalmanA No it should not match, and as I mentioned above there won't be any duplicate values in each row

Comment: @sheikh but you have three nulls in last row

Comment: @SalmanA When All 4 parameters will match in a single row, it should return TRUE, otherwise FALSE. This row to be TRUE '465456465',NULL,NULL,NULL means only one parameter should be  '465456465' and others should be null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I would approach is is by first creating a table with all your possible combinations of the 4 values. This can be done by creating a derived table with 4 rows, then joining it to itself 4 times, with each join ensuring that you are not picking a row that has already been picked, i.e.

```
DECLARE @Values TABLE
(
    Col1 VARCHAR(20),
    Col2 VARCHAR(20),
    Col3 VARCHAR(20),
    Col4 VARCHAR(20)
    UNIQUE (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
);

WITH Data AS
(   SELECT  Value, v.Ordinal
    FROM    (VALUES (1, @Col1), (2, @Col2), (3, @Col3), (4, @Col4)) AS v (Ordinal, Value)
)
INSERT @Values(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
SELECT  DISTINCT d1.Value, d2.Value, d3.Value, d4.Value
FROM    Data AS d1
        INNER JOIN Data AS d2
            ON d2.Ordinal NOT IN (d1.Ordinal)
        INNER JOIN Data AS d3
            ON d3.Ordinal NOT IN (d1.Ordinal, d2.Ordinal)
        INNER JOIN Data AS d4
            ON d4.Ordinal NOT IN (d1.Ordinal, D2.Ordinal, d3.Ordinal);
```

With a really simple example where `@Col1` = 'A', and all others are `NULL` you'll end up with something like:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NULL | NULL | NULL | A |
| NULL | NULL | A | NULL |
| NULL | A | NULL | NULL |
| A | NULL | NULL | NULL |

You can then use `INTERSECT` to check against your table. The benefit of this is that `INTERSECT` does `NULL` matching, i.e. `SELECT NULL INTERSECT SELECT NULL` will return a record, whereas `SELECT NULL WHERE NULL = NULL` will not.

```
IF EXISTS
    (   SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
        FROM    SampleData
        INTERSECT
        SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
        FROM    @Values
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Data Matched';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Data not Matched';
END
```

The main advantage of this method (aside from returning your expected results) is that it can take advantage of an index on SampleData, so if you add:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_SampleData ON dbo.SampleData (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4);
```

Then this will be used when using `INTERSECT`, but isn't with your logic as it stands:

[image]

With the small data set as it stands this doesn't make much difference, but with much larger data sets it will do. The above is with 200k rows in SampleData.

So your full procedure will be something like:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.ValidateSampleData(
 @Col1 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Col2 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Col3 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
,@Col4 VARCHAR(20) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Values TABLE
    (
        Col1 VARCHAR(20),
        Col2 VARCHAR(20),
        Col3 VARCHAR(20),
        Col4 VARCHAR(20)
        UNIQUE (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
    );

    WITH Data AS
    (   SELECT  Value, v.Ordinal
        FROM    (VALUES (1, @Col1), (2, @Col2), (3, @Col3), (4, @Col4)) AS v (Ordinal, Value)
    )
    INSERT @Values(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
    SELECT  DISTINCT d1.Value, d2.Value, d3.Value, d4.Value
    FROM    Data AS d1
            INNER JOIN Data AS d2
                ON d2.Ordinal NOT IN (d1.Ordinal)
            INNER JOIN Data AS d3
                ON d3.Ordinal NOT IN (d1.Ordinal, d2.Ordinal)
            INNER JOIN Data AS d4
                ON d4.Ordinal NOT IN (d1.Ordinal, D2.Ordinal, d3.Ordinal);

    IF EXISTS
        (   SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
            FROM    SampleData
            INTERSECT
            SELECT  Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
            FROM    @Values
        )
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Data Matched';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Data not Matched';
    END
END
```

---

**ADDEDNUM**

To answer the question in the comment:

> I got this warning while creating Index on actual table. Can you explain ? Warning! The maximum key length for a nonclustered index is 1700 bytes. `The index 'IX_SampleData' has maximum length of 2000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.`

Presumably your actual columns are larger than specified in the question (`VARCHAR(20)`)? As the warning says, the maximum key length is 1700bytes., so the required storage for all 4 columns must be less than that. Each `VARCHAR` character requires one byte of storage, so the maximum for `VARCHAR(20)` is 20 bytes, for 4 columns your maximum is 80 bytes. If however your columns are `VARCHAR(500)` then your maximum size is 2000 bytes. Since `VARCHAR` is variable, each value will only take as much space as needed. So if you enter `A` into a column defined as `VARCHAR(500)` it will still only take ` byte.

Assuming that your columns are `VARCHAR(500)` and you try and add the following:

```
INSERT INTO SampleData(Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
SELECT REPLICATE('A', 500), REPLICATE('B', 500), REPLICATE('C', 500), REPLICATE('D', 500)
```

In summary, if you are going to use all 500 characters in all 4 columns, then your insert will fail. If you have been very liberal with your column length, and the total length in all 4 columns is always going to be less than 1700 characters, then you will be fine (although, if you have been liberal with your column length, then perhaps resize them accordingly - although there is no cost in terms of additional storage there are other costs with defining columns larger than you need, so best to be as accurate as possible with column lengths).

Comment: Making this indexable is wonderful. I couldn't think of a way other than forcing the data to be ordered. Well done! (Patronising tone unintended, my apologies)

Comment: I am trying this solution on my actual dataset which contains 4948400 rows currently and will definitely increase

Comment: @Charlieface That was what I originally had, but had to change it to `UNIQUE` because with a primary key the table won't allow nulls, since a nullable column can't be part of a primary key. @MattBaille - Cheers. no problem, it was taken as intended :)

Comment: Ah fair enough.

Comment: @GarethD I got this warning while creating Index on actual table. Can you explain ? Warning! The maximum key length for a nonclustered index is 1700 bytes. The index 'IX_SampleData' has maximum length of 2000 bytes. For some combination of large values, the insert/update operation will fail.

Comment: @SheikhM.Haris My answer to that got a bit too long for a comment, so have added it to the end of the actual answer above